# Count value of inputs with same name and copy final value to another input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have i div with multiple inputs with same name:

```
<div class="cart_items_goes_up">
    <input type="hidden" value="4" name="menu_item_id[]" class="single_menu_item">
    <input type="hidden" value="3" name="menu_item_id[]" class="single_menu_item">
    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="menu_item_id[]" class="single_menu_item">
</div>
```

I need to count all these values of the input with name menu_item_id[] and copy the result value to another input with class "**order_sum**".

I know how to take all values into an array but don't know how to sum them and copy to my new input.

**My progress:**

```
jQuery(".cart_items_goes_up input[name='menu_item_id[]']").map( function() { 
  return jQuery(this).val();
} ).get();
```

Any idea? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not too far, just that the approach you too would have you go through two loops. Therefore, rather than use `map`, use `each`:

```
var sum = 0;
jQuery(".cart_items_goes_up input[name='menu_item_id[]']").each( function() { 
     sum += +this.value;
});
jQuery('input.order_sum').val( sum );
```

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/SBqbC/)

Comment: Very well friend. Glad I could be of help.